# Duplicate identifiers in typescript, react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio, npm, version-control

I have a standard react project. For some reason I get a large quantity of duplication errors in
near all files in the follwing directory:

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.3\node_modules@types\

I believe it has something to do with me attempting to change my version of react.

Is there a way to wipe all files in this directory, and reinstall them using NPM?

Screenshot of errors for context:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typescript issue.

this mybe help you: "skipLibCheck": true to tsconfig.json.